# Create paths layer without duplicating geometrical data

Tags: qgis

I have a grid of lines in a geopackage multiline layer (*layer_grid*). Using the geometrical information contained in this layer I want to create a second layer (*layer_paths*) that store information (name, description, length, ...) of some paths that can be obtained connecting the lines, but **without duplicating geometrical data**.

Avoiding the duplication is important since I need to use the obtained database in a mobile application.

How can I perform this task?

I'm using QGIS 3.4.14

EDIT

I'll try to explain with a very simple example.

[image: Example]

Lets say that the *layer_grid* (that contains all the geometric data of the road that i'm considering) is represented by the orange lines. In this layer are stored also the properties of the road, such as for example the type of road (asphalt, dirt, ..). Apparently, every line between two intersections is a different vector in the layer.

In the second layer I want to store the properties of an itinerary between, for example, point A and point B. But I don't want to re-store the geometric data in this level since I need to download these layers (exported in geoJson) from a mobile app.

I hope that I explained the concept.

Clearly, I'll have a greater number of lines and of itineraries and for this reason I need to save as much data as possible.

Comment: Can you please add some more information about your problem? An image can help a lot. For sure your problem can be solved using the Geometry by expression and the expression ``` intersection```

Comment: Yes, of course! I edited the question

Comment: Thanks. In my opinion, you should have a rule that helps to understand which are going to be your itineraries:  a layer with starting and ending points, the shortest or the longest distance between the points, etc... differently it is just a random union of lines.

Comment: The itineraries are fixed. You can imagine them as touristic roads. The parameters of the layer_paths are like the beauty of the itinerary, their difficulty if you go by foot and so on. So from point A from point B I know that the path has to be exacly that one with blue arrows (for example). The grid is basically the union of all the itineraries, but helps for two reason:

Comment: -  data saving, so I don't have to repeat the many paths that are contained in more than one itinerary
- scalability: one day I can decide to propose a new itinerary without adding geometrical information. Moreover, a function in the mobile app could be that the user can build its own itinerary to go from poin C to point D even if it is not present in the "pre-built" itineraries

Comment: Got it now. My first impression was wrong. You need to work with *Network Analysis* and paths. I can suggest giving a look to the QGIS official documentation here https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html?highlight=network

Comment: Yes, I think that could be the correct way. I found a lot on tutorials on how to search for the shortest path between two points for example. However, in this case the new layer created with the shortest path contains also the geometrical information (the points that if connected made the path). I'm searching for something that create the path just linking the information contained in the network layer